# xboxlive authentication error 400 bad request

Tags: node.js, azure-ad-msal, msal.js, xbox-live

I'm trying to authenticate in xbox live with microsoft using msal node ( i'm using this [sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-node-samples/standalone-samples/ElectronTestApp)) and using the token I get back, the problem is that I get the error 400 (bad request) when i try to call xboxlive.

```
 await axios
        .post(
            "https://user.auth.xboxlive.com/user/authenticate",
            {
                Properties: {
                    AuthMethod: "RPS",
                    SiteName: "user.auth.xboxlive.com",
                    RpsTicket: token, // the token i get from msal
                },
                RelyingParty: "http://auth.xboxlive.com",
                TokenType: "JWT",
            },
            {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    Accept: "application/json",
                },
            }
        )
        .then((x) => console.log("success", x))
        .catch((e) => console.error("error", e));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you need to prepend `d=` to the token and then pass that as the value for RpsTicket. This was based on the [xbox-webapi-node npm module](https://github.com/unknownskl/xbox-webapi-node/blob/master/src/authentication.js#L306).

```
await axios.post(
   "https://user.auth.xboxlive.com/user/authenticate",
   {
       Properties: {
           AuthMethod: "RPS",
           SiteName: "user.auth.xboxlive.com",
           RpsTicket: "d=" + token, // the token
       },
       RelyingParty: "http://auth.xboxlive.com",
       TokenType: "JWT",
    },
    {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Accept: "application/json",
        },
     }
)
.then((x) => console.log("success", x))
.catch((e) => console.error("error", e));
```